# How do I draw this box plot in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, boxplot

I currently have this dataframe like this:

```py
| patient type                |   asir |    aspr |
|:----------------------------|-------:|--------:|
| definitive dyalisis patient | 2975.6 | 15808.1 |
| kidney transplant patient   |  362   |  4469.3 |
```

**Here patient type is the index**

Right now, I'm trying to create a pandas box plot that has 4 box plots in total, 2 of which are the `asir` and `aspr` values for `definitive dialysis patient` and 2 more for `kidney transplant patient`.

Currently, I've tried to code it out with this following code:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# import the csv file
dataname = 'Datasets\\age-standardised-incidence-rate-and-prevalence-rate-for-definitive-dialysis-and-transplant.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(dataname)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# drop the year column away as we want together all the definitive dialysis patient data and the kidney transplant patient data together.abs
df2 = df.drop(['year'],axis=1)

# sum up all the data for the respective patien_type according to their respective asir and aspr
df3 = df2.groupby(df2['patient_type']).sum()
df4 = df3.rename(columns = {'patient_type':'patient_type','asir':'asir','aspr':'aspr'})

# pivot the table so that we can use the patient_type to plot out the bar plot
# df4 = df4.pivot_table(columns=['patient_type'])

# plot out the box plot 
bplot = df4.boxplot(by='patient_type',column=['asir','aspr'],grid=True,figsize=(40,20),patch_artist=True,fontsize=20)
plt.title('Boxplot Of Age Standardised incidence rate and prevalence rate for definitive dialysis and transplant patients.',fontsize=20)
# plt.legend(df4['patient_type'],fontsize=20)
plt.show()
df4
```

But it ended up looking like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm assuming that you want 4 box plots with each type: `asir`, `aspr`, `definitive dyalisis patient` and `kidney transplant patient`.

Let's say your initial dataframe looks like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'asir': [2975.6, 362.0], 'aspr':[15808.1, 4469.3],
    'patient type': ['definitive dyalisis patient',
            'kidney transplant patient']})
```

```py
| patient type                |   asir |    aspr |
|:----------------------------|-------:|--------:|
| definitive dyalisis patient | 2975.6 | 15808.1 |
| kidney transplant patient   |  362   |  4469.3 |
```

Draw the first plot where we show `asir` and the `aspr` counts:

```py
df = df.set_index('patient type')
df.boxplot(grid=True,figsize=(40,20),patch_artist=True,fontsize=20)
```

This shows, 
[image]

Now transpose your data frame to plot the `definitive dyalisis patient` and `kidney transplant process`.

```py
t_df = df.T
```

The data frame looks like this now:

```py
|      |   definitive dyalisis patient |   kidney transplant patient |
|:-----|------------------------------:|----------------------------:|
| asir |                        2975.6 |                       362   |
| aspr |                       15808.1 |                      4469.3 |
```

Now plot this just like before:

```py
t_df.boxplot(grid=True,figsize=(40,20),patch_artist=True,fontsize=20)
```

The plot looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. With reference to the 2nd box plot chart, what if i want to plot the box plot for the 1st row, which is the row for ```asir```. Because currently, if im not wrong, the 2nd box plot chart is just only the ```aspr```  plot.

Comment: I think you need more info on how box plots work. Please read [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) and rephrase what you want to achieve exactly.